# Метод Main не хочет определяться

Tags: c#, wpf

***P.S.  Проблема решилась перезапуском Visual Studio***

Только начал работать с приложением на WPF, и посмотрев, понял, что у него нету метода Main.
Покопав в интернете я понял, что метод генерируется при компиляции приложения, однако есть способ добавить его ручками. В свойствах App.xaml поставил *Действия при сборке* на *Page*, и добавил в App.xaml.cs такой код:

```
namespace MCUpdater
{
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
        var application = new App();
        application.InitializeComponent();
        application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Однако у меня все еще висит ошибка: **Программа не содержит статического метода Main, подходящего для точки входа**. Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: А что вы в конечном случае хотите сделать? Зачем вам нужен доступ к этому методу? Откройте App.xaml и после `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` добавьте `Startup="Application_Startup"`. В App.xaml.cs можно создать метод `private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)` в котором можно сделать все что нужно при запуске программы.

Comment: @Bulson, спасибо. Вопрос решен, и думаю, стоит оформить ваш комментарий в ответ, т.к. удалять вопрос, думаю, не стоит, вдруг кому-нибудь понадобится.

Comment: Сейчас сделаю ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выполнения необходимых настроек и прочих действий во время запуска приложения в WPF нужно сделать следующее:

1) Открыть файл `App.xaml` и добавить обработчик события `Startup`

```
<Application x:Class="MYAPP"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CramUp"
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:CramUp.View"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" Startup="Application_Startup">
```

2) Теперь в файле `App.xaml.cs` можно создать метод

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Запуск программы
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //организуем запуск единственной копии этой программы
        bool createdNew;
        string mutName = "MyApp";
        _Mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, mutName, out createdNew);
        if (!createdNew)
        {
            this.Shutdown();
        }

        //в случае возникновения неперехваченной ошибки
        DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
        //#if (!DEBUG)
        //    DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
        //#endif

    }
```

Comment: Ну или перегрузить `OnStartup`.

Comment: У два раза код `DispatcherUnhandledException += ...`, один раз закомментирован, один раз нет. Опечатка?

Comment: @Bulson , Имя *_Mutex* не существует в текущем контексте

Comment: @VladD можно и OnStartup, как вариант. `DispatcherUnhandledException` появился, т.к. я просто скопировал для скорости из проекта над которым работаю в данный момент.

Comment: @SKProCH выше метода `Application_Startup()` создайте поле `private System.Threading.Mutex _Mutex;`

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо.